# How to Hide the Table of Contents in DITA-OT 4.x for Shorter Documents Without Creating or Modifying Plugins

Tags: dita-ot

I am using DITA-OT 4.x to generate PDF outputs for various technical documents. Some of these are short guides, ranging from 2 to 5 pages, for which a table of contents or cover page is unnecessary and disrupts the flow of the content.

The Oxygen help suggests using the pdf-css transtype and the `hide.frontpage.toc.index.glossary parameter` in the project configuration to hide these elements. However, this is not part of a DITA-OT plugin that is no longer maintained. I use pdf2 which doesn't have this option.

I am looking for a solution that doesn't require creating or modifying plugins, as it feels like overkill for such a simple need. Additionally, I believe that the assumption that all PDF outputs must follow a book format with a table of contents seems dated, as most current technical documents, even those that are physically delivered, do not follow this format.

Is there a simpler way to hide the table of contents and cover page in DITA-OT 4.x for shorter documents? How can I achieve this for just one or two deliverables, without impacting the others?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the PDF2 output does not have specific parameters to hide the TOC, from this previous older discussion on the Oxygen XML Forum you would need to create a PDF customization and re-define some parameters in the XSLTs:
https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/post37596.html

The DITA to PDF using CSS publishing which is done using Oxygen specific publishing plugins is not deprecated or unmaintained as you said, it is our recommended approach to create the PDF, and it has various ways in which the TOC can be hidden:

https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/25.1/ug-editor/topics/dcpp_table_of_contents.html#ariaid-title11